# How to batch replace strings in a field in SQL

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

**Context and objective**

I am trying to psuedo-anonymize some product numbers in my data table. See the sample code below. The product numbers are 10 numerics and may or may not be unique for the table.

Since there are potentially other tables that I would like to link to, I would like to use a non-random way of pseudo-anonymizing the data.

System is SQLite 3.10.1. However, any type of DBMS with SQL will be fine.

My constraints are to:

- Keep the same length as the original
- Exchange every numeric digit for either another numeric digit or for a letter

**Actions I have taken**

I was literally going to go through every possible digit and update it as below. However, this feels like a very inefficient way to do it.

```
UPDATE test
SET pseudo_num = replace(pseudo_num, '0', 'B');
UPDATE test
SET pseudo_num = replace(pseudo_num, '1', 'T');
UPDATE test
SET pseudo_num = replace(pseudo_num, '2', 'A');
UPDATE test
SET pseudo_num = replace(pseudo_num, '3', 'A');
UPDATE test
SET pseudo_num = replace(pseudo_num, '4', 'D');
UPDATE test
SET pseudo_num = replace(pseudo_num, '5', '3');
UPDATE test
SET pseudo_num = replace(pseudo_num, '6', '2');
UPDATE test
SET pseudo_num = replace(pseudo_num, '7', '4');
UPDATE test
SET pseudo_num = replace(pseudo_num, '8', 'X');
UPDATE test
SET pseudo_num = replace(pseudo_num, '9', 'L');
```

**Questions**

1. Is there a quicker way to do this, e.g. through batch replacements?
2. Is there an alternative standard way to do pseudo-anonymization that I can draw on that keeps within the constraints I outline above?

**Sample code to create data table**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  prod_num varchar(14),
  owner varchar(255) default NULL,
  prod_date varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO test (prod_num,owner,prod_date) VALUES ("260619275","Kieran","Feb 10, 2018"),("316556232","Steven","Jan 6, 2020"),("625302534","Oliver","Feb 10, 2018"),("811424845","Jeremy","Apr 12, 2018"),("060961216","Quinlan","Jul 19, 2019"),("713794360","Stuart","Nov 1, 2019"),("553381666","George","Jan 8, 2019"),("978519361","Macon","Nov 26, 2018"),("352718969","Raphael","Jul 21, 2019"),("803299478","Byron","Nov 26, 2019");
INSERT INTO test (prod_num,owner,prod_date) VALUES ("696124452","Dalton","Jul 17, 2018"),("892088485","Keane","Jul 9, 2018"),("817054190","Dillon","Apr 23, 2018"),("500170097","Fitzgerald","Feb 11, 2019"),("663252252","Thomas","Apr 10, 2018"),("061983557","Alan","May 12, 2018"),("492057435","Jarrod","Apr 16, 2018"),("837802495","Shad","Mar 22, 2019"),("725698187","Mark","Jul 22, 2018"),("153352349","Akeem","Feb 19, 2018");

ALTER TABLE test 
ADD pseudo_num NVARCHAR(20);

UPDATE test 
SET pseudo_num = prod_num;
```

Comment: Is there any overall logic to the replacements?  What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: I am not sure replacing digits with known digits (or letters) is a good anonymization, as it is reversible (except for the A, which was either a 2 or a 3)

Comment: Certainly is reversible but I think that's Okay - it should be pseudo-anonymized rather than completely

Comment: If you are using SQLite, then you want a solution in SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hash (or encryption) function to convert the product numbers to strings with chars and numbers in same length. The same product numbers also get the same hash / value:

**Example on TSQL:**

```
-- preview (old and new prod_num)
SELECT prod_num, RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('SHA1', prod_num), 2), LEN(prod_num)) 
FROM test;

-- the UPDATE
UPDATE test SET pseudo_num = RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('SHA1', prod_num), 2), LEN(prod_num));
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a73bfe74a2ae8a74b97f0c77c039ecd)

**Example on MySQL:**

```
-- preview (old and new prod_num)
SELECT prod_num, UPPER(RIGHT(MD5(prod_num), LENGTH(prod_num))) 
FROM test;

-- the UPDATE
UPDATE test SET pseudo_num = UPPER(RIGHT(MD5(prod_num), LENGTH(prod_num)));
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d821f705df1ce6bccbc615abe517f080)

**Example on Oracle:**

```
-- preview (old and new prod_num)
SELECT prod_num, SUBSTR(STANDARD_HASH(prod_num, 'MD5'), LENGTH(prod_num) * -1) pseudo_prod_num 
FROM test;

-- the UPDATE
UPDATE test SET pseudo_num = SUBSTR(STANDARD_HASH(prod_num, 'MD5'), LENGTH(prod_num) * -1);
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bd09594abecc7946e223f21fa9ae1b35)

**Example PostgreSQL:**

```
-- preview (old and new prod_num)
SELECT prod_num, UPPER(RIGHT(MD5(prod_num), LENGTH(prod_num))) 
FROM test;

-- the UPDATE
UPDATE test SET pseudo_num = UPPER(RIGHT(MD5(prod_num), LENGTH(prod_num)));
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d4bc404d00b31bb59ea7cf296f68131a)

Comment: Is this conversion reproducible, so that if I want it done on another table and the same `prod_num` is present, it will produce the same `pseudo_num`?

Comment: Yes. The same prod_num is the same hash. You can check this if you look at the preview. The same product numbers have the same hash. On all big DBMS there sould be a hash function.

Comment: How would I do the same thing with PostgreSQL and Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You may try using a join here to do the replacements.  If you don't have a formal table which contains the mapping from the old to new `pseduo_num`, then we can try using a CTE.

```
WITH map AS (
    SELECT '0' AS pseudo_num, 'B' AS output UNION ALL
    SELECT '1', 'T' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2', 'A' UNION ALL
    SELECT '3', 'A' UNION ALL
    SELECT '4', 'D' UNION ALL
    SELECT '5', '3' UNION ALL
    SELECT '6', '2' UNION ALL
    SELECT '7', '4' UNION ALL
    SELECT '8', 'X' UNION ALL
    SELECT '9', 'L'
),
cte AS (
    SELECT t.pseudo_num, m.output
    FROM test t
    INNER JOIN map m
        ON t.pseudo_num = m.psuedo_num
)

UPDATE cte
SET pseudo_num = output;
```

Answer (score 1):

You said "any type of DBMS with SQL will be fine", so this is for Postgres:

In Postgres, you can use the [translate()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) function for that:

```
UPDATE test
  SET pseudo_num = translate(pseudo_num, '0123456789', 'BTAAD324XL');
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/OIMBB72939

Answer (score 0):

On Mariadb:

```
alter table test add primary key (prod_num);
replace into test(prod_num, owner, prod_date, pseudo_num)
select 
    prod_num,
    owner,
    prod_date,
    replace(
        replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                        replace(prod_num,'0','B')
                                    ,'1','T')
                                ,'2','A')
                            ,'3','A')
                        ,'4','D')
                    ,'5','3')
                ,'6','2')
            ,'7','4')
        ,'8','X')
    ,'9','L') as pseudo_num
from test;
```